# Dessins d'enfant of Dynkin diagrams?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, absolute-galois-group

Dessins d'enfant have a nice particular case of Shabat trees, where we take a tree, bicolor it, and get a polynomial map.

A very famous set of trees are the Dynkin diagrams. I wonder what are the special properties of the polynomials the dessins d'enfant with them produces.

As an example, $A_n$ produces the Chebyshev polynomials.